# Simplification canonical Ellipse equation Polar to Cartesian form

Tags: conic-sections

Request your help to trap error, trying to covert an ellipse equation form polar to rectangular form, canonical.

$$ \dfrac{p}{r} =1 - \epsilon   \cos \theta  \tag{1}$$

$$ p =  r - \epsilon x \tag{2} $$
squaring
$$(p+ \epsilon x)^2 = r^2 = x^2 + y^2  \tag{3} $$

Bring all quantities to RHS

$$ x^2 ( 1- \epsilon  ^2) - 2 p \epsilon   - p^2 + y^2= 0 \tag{4}$$

( an error occurred here, corrected)

$$ x^2 - \dfrac{2 p \epsilon   }{1-\epsilon ^2 } -  \dfrac{p^2}{1- \epsilon^2 }  x  + \dfrac {y^2}{1-\epsilon ^2 } =0  \tag{5}$$

Using standard conics notation
$$ p= b^2/a ; \, \epsilon^2 = 1 -b^2/a^2 ; \, c^2 = a^2-b^2 ; \tag{6} $$

$$\dfrac{2 p \epsilon   }{1-\epsilon ^2 } =c ; \,\, \dfrac{p^2}{( 1-\epsilon^2)} = b^2  \tag{7} $$

$$ x^2 - 2 c x - b^2 + a^2 y^2 /b^2 =0    \tag{8} $$

To shift to Cartesian coordinates x-shift  $ x-x_1 =c $

$$ ( c+ x_1)^2 - 2 c ( c+ x_1) + a^2 y^2/b^2 = b^2  \tag{9} $$

Expand and simplify

$$ {\left(x_1/a \right)}^2 + {\left(y/b \right)}^2 =1  \tag{10} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your 5th step, when you divide by $1-\epsilon^2$, you forgot to divide the last term $y^2$.  Then $1-\epsilon^2 = b^2/a^2$, by (6).  The last term on the left become $a^2y^2/b^2$.